# columne values not loaded on page refresh and serverside statesave

Tags: javascript, jquery, yadcf

I use this to save and store my state

```
"stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
    data.table_id = settings.sTableId;
    data.table_baseurl = settings.nTable.baseURI;
    // Send an Ajax request to the server with the state object
    $.ajax({
        "url": "/admin/StateSave",
        "data": {state: JSON.stringify(data)},
        "dataType": "json",
        "type": "POST",
        "success": function () {}
    });
},
stateLoadCallback: function (settings, callback) {
    var data = {};
    data.table_id = settings.sTableId;
    data.table_baseurl = settings.nTable.baseURI;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/StateLoad',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        "data": data,
        success: function (json) {
            callback(json);
        }
    });
}
```

on a refresh of the page, the filter works but alle values in the filter inputs are empty. What can i do to show them?

Comment: please provide a test page so I can debug it

Comment: can I send it in a personal message or email?